# How to pass an <s:iterator> iterated list back from a jsp to the same action class?

Tags: struts2

```
<s:iterator value="newIssues">
  <s:property value="is.description"/>
  <s:property value="is.component"/>
</s:iterator>
<input type="submit" align="bottom" value="Done" id="mysubmit"/>
```

Now, NewTickets is my action class.This class provided newIssues arraylist to iterate on it..I want the same list to work with when i press submit..how do i do it?

Comment: Why? If you're not submitting data for the list, re-create it, or keep it in session, or... If you want to create form fields, use array notation.